# Eclipse Helios install software invisible

Tags: eclipse, helios

Recently, when I try to install new software in Eclipse Helios (Help -> Install new software...), the list of plugins to install is always blank, even if I select a software site with available plugins.

If I press the "Select All" button, it will say something like "4 items selected", and it will actually install the plugins if I proceed.

As far as I can see, there is nothing in the error log. What to do?

Comment: I'm having this problem too and interested in any suggestions.

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=290395

Answer (score 0):

There is no repository in memory.
Just click add button (before search eclipse repository and copy the url's repository)
and paste your eclipse repository address